# Downgrade to Framework 4 still asks for 4.5 when I publish the project

Tags: .net, asp.net-4.5

I've developed an application on .net Framework 4.5 and the client wants to run it on windows xp, so I changed the Target Framework to 4 Client Profile and created a build and published using publishing feature of visual studio 2012 itself. But on windows xp the setup file still asks for installing .net framework 4.5.

how do I fix this?

Comment: Probably changing Target Framework should work. Have you rebuild the project?

Comment: yes, like 10 times. I even clean the solution and rebuild the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I got your problem. There are three places to change.

1. Target Framework

Right Click the project property or Alt+Enter -> Application -> Target Framework -> Select .Net Framework 4 Client Profile

1. Launch Condition

Right Click the Setup Project -> View -> Launch Condition -> Right click .Net Framework -> Properties -> Version -> Select .Net Framework 4 Client Profile

1. Prerequisite

Right click the Setup Project -> Properties -> Prerequisites -> Select .Net Framework 4 Client Profile

Now Rebuild the project.

Source : http://www.weseman.net/blog/development/c/change-target-framework/

Thanks. :)

Comment: Shafiq thx for your reply, but I'm not using separate setup project. I'm using publish feature of visual studio itself and the application has no prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

I now this is an old post but it does fix the problem with this in reply to the last onmment above.

"prerequisites" is at Right Click the project property or Alt+Enter -> Application -> Publish -> click "prerequisites" button to the right hand side, then uncheck 4.5 and check the one you need.